# Date Picker Validation on Apex

Tags: date, validation, plsql, oracle-apex

I need to write a validation statement for Start and End Date.

These are the logic I need to implement:

- Start Date should be equal to current date or future date.
- End Date should be equal to start date or greater than start date.

I have two columns in the database named START_DATE and END_DATE. 
I have two columns in Apex named 'P1_START' and 'P1_END'

I am no sure how to get started on typing out the function as I am new at querying. Any detailed suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You could choose a PL/SQL validation, and use

```
to_date(:p1_start) <= to_date(:p1_end)
```

We explicitly convert the bind variables as they are all stored as strings.
Without supplying the format, it will use the application globalisation settings.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Oracle Apex 22.2.4]

Using Apex 22.x.x
you can use the Maximum Date / Minimum Date of the Date Picker